# Debug an application for analyzing file decryption

Tags: encryption, decryption, cryptography

I have an encrypted raw data file generated by an application. This file is used in a second application to generate a readable text file based on the raw data.

I need to change a few values in the raw data file, but since the contents of the raw data file are encrypted, I wanted to find out what is the encryption mechanism that is being used on the file, so I can decrypt it, make some changes, and encrypt it back.

A sample of the file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Cuj8aTG1

Since I could not infer, based on the contents of the file, what kind of encryption is used, I wanted to know if there is a good debugger for windows that I can use to try and go through the code of the application, and see if I can check how the decryption is made.

Since I do not know if the debugger will depend on the language used, it does not use .net, that would be more easy to reverse engineer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your app windows exe or (for example) , linux elf or something else ? Is it 32 or 64 bit ? Do I understand correctly that it is not .net application ?

Comment: @ws yes, it is a windows application, not using .net, as mentioned in the question. as for the 32 or 64, good question. I cannot clarify that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to know if there is a good debugger for windows that I can
>   use

[OllyDbg v2](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html) is a good debugger for Windows.

Comment: My vote goes for winDbg